# How to trigger dropdown change event on image click

Tags: jquery, magento

I have a dropdown which updates description field in form. Now I have converted dropdown into images & want the same functionality on image click. Dropdown will be hidden element in form.

So when some one clicks on image, I want to trigger dropdown change event in background & change description as it was previously working.

```
<dl class="last">
<img dataid="11" alt="12x12 in" src="12x12_in.jpg" class="sizeimage">&nbsp;
<img dataid="12" alt="14x14 in" src="14x14_in.jpg" class="sizeimage">&nbsp;
<img dataid="13" alt="16x16 in" src="16x16_in.jpg" class="sizeimage">&nbsp;
<img dataid="14" alt="20x20 in" src="20x20_in.jpg" class="sizeimage">&nbsp;
<img dataid="6" alt="22x22 in" src="22x22_in.jpg" class="sizeimage">&nbsp;
<img dataid="7" alt="12x16 in" src="12x16_in.jpg" class="sizeimage">&nbsp;
<img dataid="8" alt="12x18 in" src="12x18_in.jpg" class="sizeimage">&nbsp;
<select class="required-entry super-attribute-select" id="attribute135" name="super_attribute[135]">
<option value="11">12x12 in</option>
<option value="12">14x14 in</option>
<option value="13">16x16 in</option>
<option value="14">20x20 in</option>
<option value="6">22x22 in</option>
<option value="7">12x16 in</option>
<option value="8">12x18 in</option>
</select>
</dl>

<script type="text/javascript">
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
$j('.sizeimage').bind('click', { imgId: $j(this).attr('dataid') },
function (evt) {
var $ddlHeader = $j("#attribute135");
$ddlHeader.val($j(this).attr('dataid')); //dropdown value changed but description not changed

//tried below methods but none of them updating description field
$ddlHeader.val($j(this).attr('dataid')).change();
$ddlHeader.val($j(this).attr('dataid')).trigger('change');
});
});
</script>
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: You need to look at the combobox example in the autocomplete documentation http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

Comment: Where you handle dropdown list change event?

Comment: $('#attribute135').change(function(){
        //some code to update description...
});

Answer (score 1):

I test your code and it works fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DrcDN/).

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('#attribute135').change(function(){
        alert('change');
    });

    $j('.sizeimage').bind('click', { imgId: $j(this).attr('dataid') },
    function (evt) {
        var $ddlHeader = $j("#attribute135");
        $ddlHeader.val($j(this).attr('dataid')).change(); //dropdown value changed but description not changed
    });
});
```

I think the problem is you remove the select element and attach it to dl element. So all events you bind to it before will be lost. You should bind it after reattaching the select element.

Comment: Actually change function is written in prototype. So I am having issue in merging jQuery with prototype.

Comment: both way (jQuery & Prototype) value in dropdown is changing perfectly. But currently issue is dropdown change event is not called in background that updates other element in form. When we set dropdown value I need to fire dropdown change event so it will update other element in form...

Answer (score 0):

Prototype example

```
$$('.sizeimage').each(function (element) {     
    Event.observe(element, 'click', function(e){
        $('attribute135').value = this.readAttribute('dataid')
    }); 
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/DrcDN/1/